# Generating a nebula cloud in circle

Tags: c#, windows, math, xna, monogame

I'm trying to generate a nebula cloud in a specified radius around a `Vector2` (Point).

Currently I'm using this code

```
public static Vector2 GeneratePosition(Vector2 position, float radius)
{
    float X = GenerateScaleFloat() * (GenerateInt(2) == 1 ? 1 : -1);
    float Y = GenerateInt((int)(radius * -(1 - Math.Abs(X))),
                          (int)(radius *  (1 - Math.Abs(X)))) / radius;

    X *= radius;
    Y *= radius;
        
    return new Vector2(X, Y);
}
```

which gives me this result:

(Origin: `0;0`, Radius: `300`, Particles: `5000`)
[image: Filled non-circle]

It looks to me like my code is generating a rotated square. How can I make it generate the positions of the particles in (and within) a more circular pattern?

**GenerateScaleFloat:** Returns a value between 0.0 and 1.0

**GenerateInt:** The standard rand.Next

**EDIT:**
This post has now been flagged as duplicate, which was not my intention. I will however leave my answer here for other googlers to find since I know how helpful it is:

New code:

```
public static Vector2 GeneratePosition(Vector2 position, float radius)
{
    float X = GenerateScaleFloat() * (GenerateInt(2) == 1 ? 1 : -1) * radius;
    float Y = float.PositiveInfinity;

    while(Y > Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(radius, 2) - Math.Pow(X, 2))
        || Y < -Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(radius, 2) - Math.Pow(X, 2)))
    {
        Y = GenerateScaleFloat() * (GenerateInt(2) == 1 ? 1 : -1) * radius;
    }
                                
    return new Vector2(X, Y) + position;
}
```

New output: (Origin: 0;0, Radius 100, Particles: 5000)
[image: Circular nebula]

Hope it'll help somebody else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for a circle area is

```
x^2 + y^2 <= r^2
```

Given a `x` you can calculate `y` like this

```
y <= +/-sqrt( r^2 - x^2 )
```

By applying different scaling factors to the axis you can create an ellipse.

---

Another possibility is to generate points in a rectangle and look if they are within the ellipse:

```
a = width / 2
b = height / 2
(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 <= 1    Where the ellipse will be centered on
                          the origin of the coordinate system.
```

This might generate more evenly distributed points.

---

**EDIT:** You can improve your new code. Instead of comparing ...

```
y > Sqrt(r^2 - x^2) OR y < -Sqrt(r^2 - x^2)
```

... you can compare

```
y^2 > r^2 - x^2
```

`y^2` is always positive since minus times minus is plus. It is often worth transforming an otherwise correct mathematical correct formula in order to make it more efficient for the computer. Calculating a square root is expensive, `Math.Pow` as well.

Also the generation of Y values between -1 and plus +1 can be achieved in an easier way by first generating a random number between 0 and 1, multiplying it by twice the radius and finally subtracting the radius.

```
float y2max = radius * radius - X * X;
do { 
    Y = 2 * radius * GenerateScaleFloat() - radius;
} while (Y * Y > y2max);
```